# Copy Constructor going to base constructor and overwriting copied values

Tags: c#, constructor, overloading, copy-constructor, default-constructor

Constructor Conundrum, I have these two constructors. One is for making a copy of the class and the other is the standard constructor. I need to call the first one so that I can use the rule in it. I shouldn't have to repeat code so I am looking for a way to keep from overwriting the two dimensions.

```
public SprinklerLineModel()
    {

        NearCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel();
        FarCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel();

        this.AddValidationRule(Rule.CreateRule(() => BranchLineDiameter, RuleMessage.GREATER_THAN_ZERO, () => BranchLineDiameter > 0));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copy Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sprinklerLineModel">Original copy of sprinklerLineModel</param>
    public SprinklerLineModel(SprinklerLineModel sprinklerLineModel)
        :this()
    {
        this.EstimatedFlow = sprinklerLineModel.EstimatedFlow;
        this.EstimatedPressure = sprinklerLineModel.EstimatedPressure;
        this.NearCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel(sprinklerLineModel.NearCrossMainDimension);
        this.FarCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel(sprinklerLineModel.FarCrossMainDimension);
        this.BranchLineDiameter = sprinklerLineModel.BranchLineDiameter;
        this.LeadLinePipeFittingLength = sprinklerLineModel.LeadLinePipeFittingLength;
        this.ExbPipeFittingLength = sprinklerLineModel.ExbPipeFittingLength;

        this.IsDirty = sprinklerLineModel.IsDirty;
    }
```

I want to be able to call the default constructor with out overwriting the two variables. Any help would be appreciated.

I suppose I could check and see if they are null but that doesn't seem like it is the best way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extract an initialization method and call said method from both constructors.

```
public SprinklerLineModel()
{
    NearCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel();
    FarCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel();
    Init();
}

public SprinklerLineModel(SprinklerLineModel sprinklerLineModel)
{
    this.EstimatedFlow = sprinklerLineModel.EstimatedFlow;
    this.EstimatedPressure = sprinklerLineModel.EstimatedPressure;
    this.NearCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel(sprinklerLineModel.NearCrossMainDimension);
    this.FarCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel(sprinklerLineModel.FarCrossMainDimension);
    this.BranchLineDiameter = sprinklerLineModel.BranchLineDiameter;
    this.LeadLinePipeFittingLength = sprinklerLineModel.LeadLinePipeFittingLength;
    this.ExbPipeFittingLength = sprinklerLineModel.ExbPipeFittingLength;
    this.IsDirty = sprinklerLineModel.IsDirty;
    Init();
}

void Init()
{
    this.AddValidationRule(Rule.CreateRule(() => BranchLineDiameter, RuleMessage.GREATER_THAN_ZERO, () => BranchLineDiameter > 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public SprinklerLineModel()
    : this(null)
{
}

/// <summary> 
/// Copy Constructor 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="sprinklerLineModel">Original copy of sprinklerLineModel</param> 
public SprinklerLineModel(SprinklerLineModel sprinklerLineModel)
{
    this.EstimatedFlow = sprinklerLineModel.EstimatedFlow;
    this.EstimatedPressure = sprinklerLineModel.EstimatedPressure;
    if (sprinklerLineModel != null)
    {
        this.NearCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel(sprinklerLineModel.NearCrossMainDimension);
        this.FarCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel(sprinklerLineModel.FarCrossMainDimension);
    }
    else
    {
        NearCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel();
        FarCrossMainDimension = new PipeDimensionModel();
    }
    this.BranchLineDiameter = sprinklerLineModel.BranchLineDiameter;
    this.LeadLinePipeFittingLength = sprinklerLineModel.LeadLinePipeFittingLength;
    this.ExbPipeFittingLength = sprinklerLineModel.ExbPipeFittingLength;

    this.IsDirty = sprinklerLineModel.IsDirty;

    this.AddValidationRule(Rule.CreateRule(() => BranchLineDiameter, RuleMessage.GREATER_THAN_ZERO, () => BranchLineDiameter > 0));
}
```

The advantage is that you have the implemntation in one place.

/Tibi